# Capistrano from Windows with Pageant

Tags: ruby, ssh, capistrano, putty, pageant

I have a simple task... `cap foreman:restart`. I'm able to access the server through PuTTY (which is using Pageant), but apparently Capistrano doesn't know about that?

```
** [out :: staging.fanmouth.com] restart: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.4640" (uid=1000 pid=13681 comm="restart fanmouth-scheduler ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Restart" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
** [out :: staging.fanmouth.com]
←[2;37mcommand finished in 8231ms←[0m
failed: "env PATH=/usr/local/rbenv/shims:$PATH RAILS_STAGE=staging sh -c 'sudo -p '\\''sudo password: '\\'' start fanmouth-scheduler || restart fanmouth-scheduler'" on staging.fanmouth.com
```

It asks me for the password... I enter it, and get that. If I type the password wrong, it tells me so (three times and exits).

**deploy.rb**

```
set :ssh_options, { :forward_agent => true }
```

Some searching on the web shows that that should be set... I've tried it with false with the same results.

I don't know much about SSH, or Pageant. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I might late to answer you. But this would help to someone else.

[image]

As shown above, you would need to load your key in "pageant". While adding key it asks for passphrase.

After getting pageant up, try to connect via capistrano.